# Getting all the information out of a JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSON that looks like this:

`"[{""email"": ""AAA"", ""updated_at"": ""AAA"", ""net_income_verified"": AAA}, {""email"": ""BBB"", ""updated_at"": ""BBB"", ""net_income_verified"": BBB}, {""email"": ""CCC"", ""updated_at"": ""CCC"", ""net_income_verified"": CCC}]"`

And I would like to get all the data from all the fields so it ends up looking like this:

| user_id | email | updated_at | net_income_verified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | AAA | AAA |
| 1 | BBB | BBB | BBB |
| 1 | CCC | CCC | CCC |

There are multiple user_ids so the number of entries in the json field could vary.

I tried going one opr one for each user_id, but since the number of entries can vary, I don't know exactly how many entries I should try.

Edit: Each user_id has a Json, so far my query loks like this:

```
SELECT user_id, json_field
FROM users
```

Comment: Like @Stefanov.sm said, there is no user_id in your json

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function to extract all entries from the list.

```sql
select j->>'email' email, j->>'updated_at' updated_at, j->>'net_income_verified' net_income_verified
from jsonb_array_elements(
'[
  {"email": "AAA", "updated_at": "AAA", "net_income_verified": 111}, 
  {"email": "BBB", "updated_at": "BBB", "net_income_verified": 222}, 
  {"email": "CCC", "updated_at": "CCC", "net_income_verified": 333}
]'::jsonb) j;
```

| email | updated_at | net_income_verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | AAA | 111 |
| BBB | BBB | 222 |
| CCC | CCC | 333 |

However I do not see where `user_id` attribute could come from.

**Edit**

Given that every record has a JSON field and `user_id` then the query looks a bit different. I would call this the "old school approach", first flatten (using a lateral join here) and then query. The `t` CTE is a mimic of the actual table.

```sql
with t (user_id, json_field) as 
(
 values  
 (1, '[{"email": "AAA", "updated_at": "AAA", "net_income_verified": 111},{"email": "BBB", "updated_at": "BBB", "net_income_verified": 222},{"email": "CCC", "updated_at": "CCC", "net_income_verified": 333}]'::jsonb)
)
select user_id, j->>'email' email,
       j->>'updated_at' updated_at, j->>'net_income_verified' net_income_verified
from t cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_field) j;
```

| user_id | email | updated_at | net_income_verified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | AAA | 111 |
| 1 | BBB | BBB | 222 |
| 1 | CCC | CCC | 333 |

Comment: True, I'll update the post. But each user id has this json.

Comment: @Edu Pls. see the edited answer.

Comment: You could replace `cross join lateral` by a simple comma `,`

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes, you are right. As a matter of personal taste I prefer the verbose option because it seems to me somewhat more clear to read.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`json_populate_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.10.1.1.1) function for that exact purpose: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4kekwLHk)

```sql
create table r1(email text, updated_at text, net_income_verified text);

select user_id, j.* from users, json_populate_recordset(null::r1,json_field) j;
```

| user_id | email | updated_at | net_income_verified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | AAA | AAA |
| 1 | BBB | BBB | BBB |
| 1 | CCC | CCC | CCC |

You first set up an table/[type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) showing what structure you want your `json` to be mapped to, then give the function an example record of that table/type along with the target `json` value. It handles it all for you.